# Formatting JSON to be compatible with Datatables with Codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, datatables

I have encountered a problem while working with the CI and Datatables
, can someone help me with this

Source Code
Modal code

```
    public function all() {
    $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
    return $query->result_array();
    }
```

SQL Returns

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_barang] => 1 [nama_barang] => Seagate HDD External 500GB [stok_barang] => 100 [harga_awal_barang] => 400000 [harga_jual_barang] => 600000 ) [1] => Array ( [id_barang] => 2 [nama_barang] => USB 8gb Advan [stok_barang] => 50 [harga_awal_barang] => 50000 [harga_jual_barang] => 80000 ) )

Controller Code

```
        public function test(){
        $this->load->model('gudang_model');
        $data=$this->gudang_model->all();
        $output=array();
        foreach ($data as $row) {
        //$column = array();
        for ($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++) {
                        $column[] = $row;
        }
                    $output['data'] = $column;
        }
        echo json_encode($output);    
    }
```

Result

> {"data":[{"id_barang":"1","nama_barang":"Seagate HDD External 500GB","stok_barang":"100","harga_awal_barang":"400000","harga_jual_barang":"600000"},{"id_barang":"1","nama_barang":"Seagate HDD External 500GB","stok_barang":"100","harga_awal_barang":"400000","harga_jual_barang":"600000"},{"id_barang":"2","nama_barang":"USB 8gb Advan","stok_barang":"50","harga_awal_barang":"50000","harga_jual_barang":"80000"},{"id_barang":"2","nama_barang":"USB 8gb Advan","stok_barang":"50","harga_awal_barang":"50000","harga_jual_barang":"80000"}]}

Can Someone help me to know how the loop in controller have the results like this

> {"data":[["1","Seagate HDD External 500GB","100","400000"],["2","USB 8gb Advan","50","50000","80000"]]}

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `array_values()` in this case:

```
$data = $this->gudang_model->all();
$output = array();
foreach($data as $k => $value) {
    $output[] = array_values($value);
}

echo json_encode(array('data' => $output));
```

Should look something like [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/TJPIwi)